# Stop slime spawning with string?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have a massive guardian farm, but it turns out that one of the chunks is also a slime chunk. I'd like to be able to stop slime from spawning on the very top area where you walk, the farm being under.

I know you can use slabs and/or other methods, but these usually look rather bad, and I need at least my top part to look half clean.

This is why I'm asking if string will stop slime spawns. If yes, string is pretty discreet, so it's rather cool, and if not, then slabs here I come!

Answer (score -1):

No. Place glowstone in the ground spaced no more than 5 blocks from another glowstone block.

Comment: Can you specify what this will achieve? And maybe why string won't work?

Comment: [Slime spawning in slime chunks is not affected by light level](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Slime#.22Slime_chunks.22)